# Why is a list giving me a syntax error in Python?

Tags: python

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
url = "https://remoteok.io/"
response = requests.get(url,timeout=5)
content= BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml") jobArr = []
for post in content.findAll('table', attrs={"id":"jobboard"}):
    postObject={
    "company": post.find('td', attrs={"class": "company position company_and_position"}).text.encode('utf-8'),
    "job name": post.find('h3', attrs={"itemprop": "name"}).text.encode(utf-8),
    "title": post.find('h2', attrs={"itemprop": "title"}).text.encode(utf-8),
    "tags": post.find('td', attrs={"class": "tags"}).text.encode(utf-8),
    "time": post.find('td', attrs={"class": "time"}).text.encode(utf-8),
    "description": post.find('div', attrs={"class": "description"}).text.encode(utf-8),
    "markdown": post.find("div", attrs={"class": "markdown"}).text.encode(utf-8)
    }
    print postObject
```

But every time I try to run the file, this is the error that I'm getting:

```
 File "/home/user/Desktop/pythonscrap/webscraper.py", line 6
    content= BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml") jobArr = [];
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.044s]
```

I don't understand what I'm missing - please help!

Comment: Just a remainder. Start using `Python3.x` cause the support for `Python2.x` will be over by end of 2019.

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
content= BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml") jobArr = []
```

doesn't make any sense. It has two statements, so they need to be on two separate lines:

```
content= BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
jobArr = []
```

You could also use a semicolon to separate the two statements, but that is subjectively extremely bad style and just generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a new line and also appear to have an unwanted semi-colon (although this only appears in the error that you have provided, rather than the code sample):

```
content= BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml") jobArr = [];
```

should actually be:

```
content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
jobArr = []
```

Comment: It can, however, be done like `content= BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml");  jobArr = []`.